# Declaring type in array?

Tags: arrays, class, swift2

I'd like to create a class instance within an array declaration.  How is that done?

Something similar to the following:

```
myclassA.myarray = [ClassB() {name="Cleaning", deptId=12}, ClassB() {name="Repairs", deptId=30]
```

Where the array type is:

```
class ClassB : NSObject {
  var name:String?
  var deptId:Int?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array type would be `ClassB`. You also have to create an initializer for your `ClassB`. Example:

```
class ClassB: NSObject {
    var name:String?
    var deptId:Int?
    init(name: String, deptId: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.deptId = deptId
    }
}

class ClassA {
    var myarray:[ClassB] = []
}

let myclassA = ClassA()

myclassA.myarray = [ClassB(name: "Cleaning", deptId: 12), ClassB(name: "Repairs", deptId: 30)]
```